# Access VBA slow after first run

Tags: performance, ms-access, vba

I have a general question. I think it is not code related.
I have a small access program using forms, SQL and VBA.

The VBA mainly calculate pretty simple things, but with a lot of data and some SQL runs. I have a status bar where i can see "percentage done". 
I start the script by clearing all tables and after that running all queries to make sure they're empty.
I then run through the data. It works good.
It takes around 2 mins.

I then do it again.
But now it takes 10 mins. For the same procedure.

If i restart access, it takes 2 mins the first time, then 10 mins afterwards.

When i restart access, the tables are still filled. So it is not because they are empty.

Is there a command to clear all memory or whatever might be needed?

Any suggestions?

The code that runs 10x slower:

```
For counter = 1 To n_bins
    Application.Echo False

    DoCmd.OpenQuery "q_PowerBinned"
    If DCount("*", "q_PowerBinned") = 0 Then
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "q_000"
        DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM q_000"
        DoCmd.Close
        strTMP = (counter - 1) * [Forms]![f_main]![PowerBinCombo] & " - " & counter * [Forms]![f_main]![PowerBinCombo] & " kW"
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO q_000 (Bin, Zero1, Zero2, Zero3, Zero4, Zero5) VALUES ('" & strTMP & "','0','0','0','0','0');"
        DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "q_Move000"
        DoCmd.Close
    Else
        DoCmd.Close
    End If

    DoCmd.OpenQuery "q_Average_Temp"
    DoCmd.Close
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "q_MoveAverage"

    DoCmd.OpenQuery "q_PowerBinned_VG"
    If DCount("*", "q_PowerBinned_VG") = 0 Then
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "q_000_VG"
        DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM q_000_VG"
        DoCmd.Close
        strTMP = (counter - 1) * [Forms]![f_main]![PowerBinCombo] & " - " & counter * [Forms]![f_main]![PowerBinCombo] & " kW"
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO q_000_VG (Bin, Zero1, Zero2, Zero3, Zero4, Zero5) VALUES ('" & strTMP & "','0','0','0','0','0');"
        DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "q_Move000_VG"
        DoCmd.Close
    Else
        DoCmd.Close
    End If

    DoCmd.OpenQuery "q_Average_Temp_VG"
    DoCmd.Close
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "q_MoveAverage_VG"
    Application.Echo True

    ' Theoretical of Measured Power Curve

    Percentage = ((counter) / (n_bins)) * 100
    strStatus = "Binned " & Percentage & " %"

    Call dsp_progress_AfterUpdate
    Me.Refresh
    dsp_progress.SetFocus
    dsp_progress.SelStart = 0
    dsp_progress.SelLength = 0
    DoEvents
Next counter
```

Comment: It would help if we could see some code that is responsible for this effect.

Comment: I could do that, but it is around 1000 lines.... I dont think it is the code that slows it down, since i run the exact same thing twice...

Comment: I have added the part that i know is very slow. But i dont know if that is the only slow part, i only know that this is because i have the status bar running on that loop.

Comment: Why are you opening Queries and closing it? `DoCmd.OpenQuery "q_PowerBinned"`, `DoCmd.OpenQuery "q_000"`, `DoCmd.OpenQuery "q_Move000"` They are all unnecessary. Unless they are Action Queries. If that is the case, would explain your problem of execution time.

Comment: I do that to update the query every loop. I then run the q_MoveSomething (Appends) queries to move the data to tables to store the data calculated in the loops. Why does that explain the execution time? What is the explanation for taking first 2 mins (acceptable) and then 10-15 mins (unacceptable)? And then again after a restart of access, 2 mins...

Comment: BTW, is there a setting in access VBA to automatically do the tabulation of code inside if statements etc., like you just did? I have to do that manually now.

Comment: I should have added the explanations, when an Action Query is performed `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and followed by a `DELETE` the space allocated is not ideally used efficiently. However when you close and open (hopefully) a compact and repair will sort this out. So a lot more quicker. You do not need to OPEN a query before performing a DCount.

Comment: Okay, what is my alternative? I will of course try and remove the open query before DCount. But actually, the if statements are never true. They should never be = 0, it is only to fill in zeroes in the table, if i have a dataset with a case with no data (I divide it into sections based on a value, and sometimes, the value might not we present, but it is 99 % of the cases)

Comment: For me you open more times than close. It's better if you create different procedures and call it. You open PowerBinned but if dcount=0 you not close it. This is the main problem to slow-down the access to SQL every time that you execute.

Comment: Hi Mastercafe. Thank you for looking into my code. I do think i close it, because the "q_Move000" is an append query and does not need a close command. So the close command after is closing the q_PowerBinned query.

Answer (score 1):

This happens for one of my access databases. I find that if I do a `compact & repair` after the appropriate tables have been emptied, the vba run-time returns to the short time again. Not the most elegant of solutions I must admit.

Comment: I've been doing it manually. From what I understand, you can not compact & repair through code.